# T5 multilabel classification using tf

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to do multilabel classification on a corpus of data which has labels too. When
The data looks like this after adding the tag in the front for each row:
print(texts)
0        multilabel classification: how time changes th...
1        multilabel classification: hawaii has been in ...
2        multilabel classification: not all alaskans ar...
3        multilabel classification: you should read rap...
4        multilabel classification: giving stupid kids ...

I am trying to tokenize above and since there are multiple rows, I am guessing i have to go in a loop. What I am trying understand is, how do I get the input_ids, attention_mask? should I go in a loop to get for each row or for the entire text?
am I doing it right above by adding the tag multilabel classification: for each row? am totally confused whether my assumption is wrong or whether this is the way to do it.

my code is:

```
src_tokenized = TOKENIZER.encode_plus(
            texts[0], 
          max_length=SRC_MAX_LENGTH,
            pad_to_max_length=True,
            truncation=True,
            return_attention_mask=True,
            return_token_type_ids=False,
            return_tensors='tf'
        )
src_input_ids = src_tokenized['input_ids']
src_attention_mask = src_tokenized['attention_mask']

t5_summary_ids = t5_model.generate(src_input_ids)
```

am feeling am doing wrong by running it row by row. but am not sure. I googled for it and all i see multilabel classification example is using pytorch not tf.

Appreciate all the help. TIA

Comment: Please format your code snippet in the question properly, it's hard to understand the  `for each row: print(texts) ...` part, so it's underclear what you're asking about.

Comment: the above code is basically in tf is using TFT5. This piece of code has to run for n number of rows each row contains a text and multi labels for that text ie ''' i am jumping happily you moron" [non toxic, toxic]. there are multiple of these rows in the corpus. to run T5 i need to get attention mask and input ids for each row

Comment: Format the code properly and make it a little more readable, add your comments to the question. That'll help prevent others in the Stackoverflow community from closing the question =)